# Идентификация пользователей пришедших с поисковиков

Tags: php

Добрый день. Образовалась необходимость выполнения дополнительных действий пользователям пришедших с поисковиков. Ранее я реализовал это с помощью реффера, искал там google,yandex,mail и т.д.
В общих чертах ситуация такая:
Есть index.php на который заходят с поисковиков. С этого индекса пользователи могут перейти на script.php, и в случае если юзер пришел с поисковика, то требуется выполнить дополнительную часть кода.

```
$reffer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
$new_url = parse_url($reffer); 
if(preg_match("/ya\.|yandex\.|google\.|mail\.|rambler\.|vk./",$new_url['host'])) { 
//тут мой дополнительный код
}
```

Вот пример кода который я использовал..

Comment: Самое простое - для юзеров с поисковиков формировать ссылку на script.php c дополнительным гет параметром, если параметр есть выполняется нужный код. Второй вариант - ставить куку и на второй странице ее читать

Comment: В сессию ставьте флаг о том, что юзер пришел с поисковика.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [сессию](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) для этого или [куки](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). На `index.php` ставьте их, а на других страницах проверяйте (хотя ведь юзеры могу и на другие страницы с поисковиков заходить).